# Ontop can not Import mappings

Tags: h2, protege, r2rml

I am trying to make this tutorial
http://optique-project.eu/training-programme/module-ontop/

In this step

> Import mappings: Ontop>>Import R2RML mappings…  <northwind-mapping-M2T2.ttl >

I am waiting more than a hour and no result. This is what it is. And I have no idea whta can I do. [image]

The problem comes with the import of mappings.

Comment: What is the size of the file, and is there any message in the protégé console?

Comment: Using Protégé 5.5 with Ontop 4.2, the mappings loaded fine and in a couple of seconds. I had to edit a little bit the SQL script with the NORTHWIND database, though.